# Why do large organisations still not sign various EXEs?

Tags: windows-7, digital-signature

We run a controlled Windows 7 environment and have several applications that are digitally signed by the publisher that run under user context fine. However, even now we still get vendors large and small providing us with non signed exe which we have to create “hash rules” in AppLocker that need updating every time the software is updating.

In some cases we get an application from a vendor that has a mixture of both signed and unsigned executables. This infuriates me!

I was just wondering, why would these companies not simply sign all their software? Is it just sloppy development or is there a genuine reason such as a cost per exe signed?

Comment: we can't answer this here. Ask this the support of the tools. Such a certificate costs several hundreds of dollars and mabay they don't want to pay it, but this is pure speculation, that's why I voted to close your question.

Comment: Have you thought of the bureaucracy needed in a large organization to manage and secure signature keys?